# setting up autotools to link single system library statically

Tags: gcc, autotools

I have a project, where I want to link one of system libraries statically. The project uses GNU build system.

In configure.ac I have:

```
AC_CHECK_LIB(foobar, foobar_init)
```

On development machine this library is installed in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu. It is detected, but it is linked dynamically, which causes issues, as it is not present on some machines. Linking it statically (-Wl,-Bstatic etc.) works fine, but I don't know how to set this up in autotools. I tried forcing this into Makefile.am link flags for the project, but it still gives a preference to dynamic library.
I also tried using --enable-static with ./configure, but it seems to have no effect on system libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to link the whole program statically, then you should pass the `--disable-shared` option to `configure`.  You might or might not need also to pass `--enable-static`, depending on the default value for that option (which you can influence via your `configure.ac` file).  You really should consider doing this.

You should also consider making this the installer's problem, not the build system's.  Let it be the installer's responsibility to ensure that all the shared libraries needed by the program are provided by the systems where it is installed.  This is *very* common; in fact, it is one of the inspirations for package-management systems such as `yum` / `dnf` and `apt`, and their underlying packaging formats.

If you insist on linking only one library statically, while linking everything else dynamically, then you'll need to jump through a few more hoops.  The objective will be to emit link options that cause just that library to be linked statically, without changing other libraries' linking.  With the GNU toolchain, and supposing that the program is otherwise being linked dynamically, that would be this combination of options:

```
-Wl,-Bstatic -lfoobar -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

Now consider [the documentation of the `AC_CHECK_LIB()` macro](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Libraries.html#index-AC_005fCHECK_005fLIB-341):

> Macro: `AC_CHECK_LIB` (*`library`*, *`function`*, [*`action-if-found`*],
>   [*`action-if-not-found`*], [*`other-libraries`*])
>
> [...] *`action-if-found`* is a list of shell commands to run if the link with the library succeeds; *`action-if-not-found`* is a list of shell
>   commands to run if the link fails. If *`action-if-found`* is not
>   specified, the default action prepends `-llibrary` to `LIBS` and defines
>   '`HAVE_LIBlibrary`' (in all capitals). [...]

Note in particular the default behavior in the event that the optional arguments are not provided (your present case) -- that's not quite what you want, at least not by itself.  I suggest providing at least an alternative behavior for *`action-if-found`* case, and you could consider also making `configure` fail in the *`action-if-not-found`* case.  The latter is left as an exercise; implementing just the former might look like this:

```
AC_CHECK_LIB([foobar], [foobar_init], [
  LIBS="-Wl,-Bstatic -lfoobar -Wl,-Bdynamic $LIBS"
  AC_DEFINE([HAVE_LIBFOOBAR], [1], [Define to 1 if you have libfoobar.])
])
```

You should also pay attention to the order of your `AC_CHECK_LIB()` invocations.  As its docs go on to say:

> This macro is intended to support building `LIBS` in a right-to-left
>   (least-dependent to most-dependent) fashion such that library
>   dependencies are satisfied as a natural side effect of consecutive
>   tests. Linkers are sensitive to library ordering so the order in which
>   `LIBS` is generated is important to reliable detection of libraries.

If you find that you still aren't getting what you want, then have a look at the link commands that `make` actually executes.  You need to understand what's wrong about them before you can determine how to fix the problem.

With all that said, I observe that the above treatment is basically a hack, and it makes your build system much less resilient.  It introduces dependencies on GNU toolchain options (which some other toolchains may nevertheless accept), and it assumes dynamic linking is being performed overall.  It may be possible to resolve those issues with additional Autoconf code, but I urge you to instead go with one of the first two alternatives I described.

Comment: Note, too, that static linking depends on having a static version of the library.  This is a different and entirely separate file from the shared version, and presence of one does not require or imply presence of the other.  On Unix, the conventional name for the static library would be `libfoobar.a`, whereas the shared library would be `libfoobar.so`.

Comment: I was trying to manually add -Wl,-Bstatic in AC_CHECK_LIB (before), but failed. Your version works fine and that is what I was looking for. Alternative solution that worked, but seemed even more hacky, was to take "link" rule from Makefile.in, copy it to Makefile.am and add -Wl,-Bstatic there.

Comment: I agree that using installer is probably the right solution, but this is simpler (for now). Will have to look into it eventually.